# Help Drawing Figure and Understanding Proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Circle $S_1$ with diameter $AB$ intersects circle $S_2$ centered at $A$ at points $C$ and $D$. Through point $B$ a line is drawn; it intersects $S_2$ at point $M$ that lies inside $S_1$ and it intersects $S_1$ at point $N$. Prove that $MN^2 = CN \cdot ND$.

This is a solution that I found online.

**Solution:** Let lines $BM$ and $DN$ meet $S_2$ at points $L$ and $C_1$, respectively. Let us prove that lines $DC_1$ and $CN$ are symmetric through line $AN$. Since $BN \perp $NA $ $it suffices to verify that $\angle CNB = \angle BND$. But arcs $CB$ and $BD$ are equal. Arcs $C_1M$ and $CL$ are symmetric through line $AN$, hence, they are equal and, therefore, $\angle MDC_1 = \angle CML$. Besides, $\angle CNM = \angle MND$. Thus, $\triangle MCN \sim \triangle DMN$, i.e., $\displaystyle\frac{CN}{MN} = \frac{MN}{DN}$.

**My Problem:** I understand that we ultimately need to prove that $\triangle MCN \sim \triangle DMN$. However, I am not understanding the solution from online with the symmetry. Is there another method to use to prove these 2 triangles similar?

**This is what I have come up with so far:**

If we can prove that $\triangle MCN \sim \triangle DMN$ we are done. Exted $BA$ until it hits circle $S_2$ at point $K$>. Then $\triangle AKC$ is isoscles with $\angle AKC = \angle ACK$ both shining on arc $AC$. If we draw the tangent at $C$ to circle $S_2$ such that it intersects $AN$ at point $L$ and circle $S_1$ at $T$ ($T$ not equal to $B$) we get $\angle ACL = \angle ACT = 90^\circ$. Denote $\angle ACK = \theta$.

So arc $AC = 2\theta$ and denote arc $AN = 2\alpha$.

Then $\angle NMC = \frac{1}{2}arcNC$ $=$ $\alpha + \theta$.

$\angle KCL = 90^\circ - \theta$.

Denote $\angle MCB = \beta$. Then $\angle NCM = 90^\circ - \alpha - \beta$.

Looking at $\triangle MCN$, $\angle MNC = 90^\circ - \theta + \beta$.

Comment: Which part of the proof is giving you trouble?

Comment: @epimorphic I understand that we ultimately need to prove that $\triangle MCN \sim \triangle DMN$. However, I am not understanding the symmetric solution. Is there another method to use to prove those triangles similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible proof. There is another, fairly different, but takes too long to write it as well.

Let $B_2$ be the second intersection of line $BN$ with circle $S_2$, the first one being $M$. Let $C_2$ be the second intersection of line $CN$ with circle $S_2$, the first one being $C$. Because $B$ is the midpoint of the arc $\text{arc}(CBD)$, the line $BN$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, CND$ with $M$ and $B_2$ lying on $BN$, so $$\angle \, MND = \angle \, MNC = \angle \, B_2NC_2$$ Furthermore, $\angle \, ANB = 90^{\circ}$ because $AB$ is a diameter of $S_1$. Hence $AN$ is orthogonal to the chord $MB_2$ which means that $AN$ is the orthogonal bisector of $NB_2$. Therefore $MN = B_2N$ and $$\angle \, ANM = 90^{\circ} = \angle \, ANB_2$$ 
[image]

All together 
$$ \angle \, AND = \angle \, ANM + \angle \, MND = 90^{\circ} + \angle \, MND = $$ $$= 90^{\circ} + \angle \, B_2NC_2 = \angle \, ANB_2 + \angle \, B_2NC_2 = \angle \, ANC_2$$  Since $AC = AC_2$, the triangle $ACC_2$ is isosceles so $$\angle \, AC_2N = \angle \, AC_2C = \angle \, ACC_2 = \angle \, ACN$$ However, as angles inscribed in circle $S_1$
$$\angle \, ACN = \angle \, ABN = \angle \, ADN$$ so $$\angle \, ADN = \angle \, AC_2N$$ Combined with the already proved $\angle \, AND = \angle \, ANC_2$ it yields that triangles $AND$ and $ANC_2$ are congruent. Therefore $$ND = NC_2$$ By the intersecting chord theorem 
$$CN \cdot ND = CN \cdot NC_2 = MN \cdot B_2N = MN^2$$

Comment: wow thanks +1 !

Comment: @rover2 check out the other proof. it's different and it uses similarity of triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof. Let $C_1$ be the second intersection point of line $CM$ with circle $S_1$, the first one being $C$.  Let $D_1$ be the second intersection point of line $DM$ with circle $S_1$, the first one being $D$. Let $E$ be the intersection point of diameter $AB$ with $S_2$.

Observe that $AD = AC = AE$ since $A$ is the center of $S_2$. Hence triangles $ADE$ and $ACE$ are isosceles. Furthermore, $B$ is the midpoint of $\text{arc}(CBD)$ so $AB$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, CAD$. Therefore $$\angle \, EAD = \angle \, BAD = \angle \, BAC = \angle \, EAC = \beta$$ which means that the two isosceles triangles $ADE$ and $ACE$ are congruent. Thus, $\angle \, AED = \angle \, AEC = 90^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2}\,\beta$. Consequently, $$\angle \, CED = \angle \, AEC + \angle \, AED = 180^{\circ} - \beta$$  [image]

As inscribed angles in circle $S_2$
$$\angle \, CMD = \angle \, CED = 180^{\circ} - \beta$$ hence
$$\angle \, C_1MD_1 = \angle\, CMD = 180^{\circ} - \beta$$ As inscribed angles in circle $S_1$
$$\angle \, BD_1D = \angle \, BAD = \beta $$ so $$\angle \, BD_1M + C_1MD_1 = \angle \, BD_1D + \angle \, C_1MD_1 = \beta + 180^{\circ} - \beta = 180^{\circ}$$ which means that $BD_1$ is parallel to $MC_1$. Analogously, as inscribed angles in circle $S_1$
$$\angle \, BC_1C = \angle \, BAC = \beta$$ so $$\angle \, BC_1M + C_1MD_1 = \angle \, BC_1C + \angle \, C_1MD_1 = \beta + 180^{\circ} - \beta = 180^{\circ}$$ which means that $BC_1$ is parallel to $MD_1$. Consequently, $BC_1MD_1$ is a parallelogram which means that the two triangles $MBD_1$ and $BMC_1$ are congruent.

Finally, since chords $DD_1$ and $BN$ of circle $S_1$ intersect at point $M$, the triangles $MDN$ and $MBD_1$ are similar. Analogously, since chords $CC_1$ and $BN$ of circle $S_1$ intersect at point $M$,  the triangles $CMN$ and $BMC_1$ are also similar. However, as already shown, triangles $MBD_1$ and $BMC_1$ are congruent, so triangles $MDN$ and $CMN$ are similar. Thus
$$\frac{MN}{ND} = \frac{CM}{MN}$$ which is equivalent to $MN^2 = CM \cdot ND$.